# Firebase on AWS Lambda Import Error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, firebase, aws-lambda, firebase-admin

I am trying to connect Firebase with an AWS Lambda. I am using their `firebase-admin` sdk. I have installed and created the dependancy package as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html). But I am getting this error on Lambda:

```
 Unable to import module 'index':
 Failed to import the Cloud Firestore library for Python.
 Make sure to install the "google-cloud-firestore" module.
```

I have previously also tried setting up a similar function using node.js but I received an error message because `GRPC` was not configured. I think that this error message might be stemming from that same problem. I don't know how to fix this. I have tried:

```
pip install grpcio -t path/to/...
```

and installing `google-cloud-firestore`, but neither fixed the problem. When I run the code from my terminal, I get no errors.

Comment: Just to make sure did you try installing `google-cloud-firestore`? You mention `google-cloud-platform` which is not correct.

Comment: I see what you are saying, I think that may have been a typo on my part. Let me double check and I'll edit accordingly! :)

Comment: Any updates on this @MattBart ? Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: Nope! I was never able to get this working, so I switched over to a private personal server.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem here is that grpcio compiles a platform specific dynamic module: `cygrpc.cpython-37m-darwin.so` (in my case). According to this response you cannot import dynamic modules in a zip file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58140801

Answer (score 0):

Updating to python 3.8 fix this for me

Answer (score 0):

As Alex DeBrie mentioned in [his article on serverless.com](https://www.serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging/),

> The plugins section registers the plugin with the Framework. In the custom section, we tell the plugin to use Docker when installing packages with pip. It will use a Docker container that's similar to the Lambda environment so the compiled extensions will be compatible. You will need Docker installed for this to work.

Which means, the environment is different between Local and Lambda, so the compiled extensions would differ. If use a container to contain packages installed by pip, the container would mimic the environment of Lambda, then everything would run well.

If you use Serverless Frame work to deploy your Python app to AWS Lambda, add these lines to `serverless.yml` file:

```yaml
...
plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
...
custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux
    dockerImage: mlupin/docker-lambda:python3.9-build
...
```

then `serverless-python-requirements` would automatically open a Docker container based on `mlupin/docker-lambda:python3.9-build` image.

This container would mimic the Lamda environment, let pip install and compile everything in it. So the compiled extensions will be compatible.

This worked in my case. Hope this helps.