# Import Python Module at Runtime with AWS Lambda

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, aws-lambda

I am attempting to import the **google-cloud-firestore** module in a python script on AWS Lambda. I have the module installed in my virtual environment and upload the code/packages in a zip folder, but receive the following error.

[image]

I have successfully imported and executed a script with the **requests** module using the same approach.

I have attempted to uninstall and reinstall the following modules to my virtual environment and still have no luck: **google-cloud-firestore**, **grpcio**, **google-cloud-core**.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? What could I be missing here?

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391458/firebase-on-aws-lambda-import-error) gives me the impression that the **google-cloud-firestore** module cannot be used in a zip file. If this is the case, can I install the module at runtime?

Thank you for any and all advice!

Comment: You need to package the dependencies with your lambda. You can do so by including them within the same zip file or by creating a lambda layer that includes them.

Comment: I uploaded using the virtual environment approach documented here. So, the dependencies should be included in the zip file. It worked for the requests module, but not for google-cloud-firestore. Is there another step I need to take to include it as a dependency successfully? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html#python-package-venv

Comment: That mentions that anything besides standard Python math and logging libraries and boto3 need to be included in the zip. I'm actually surprised that requests worked without including it.  I feel like I've had to bundle it in.

Comment: Apologies if this was unclear in the original post, but requests was included in the zip and it worked successfully. I did the same thing for google-cloud-firestore and it did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I upgraded my Lambda python runtime to 3.8 and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error using `bcrypt`, I solved running this:

`pip install --target=python3 --implementation cp --python-version 3.11 --only-binary=:all: --upgrade bcrypt wheel --platform manylinux2014_x86_64`

**Note:**

If this doesn't work you can test it compressing directly your virtual environment libraries:

`zip -r ~/.pyenv/versions/users_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages python/`